# Group Data from SQL to show in WPF Tree View with Multiple Levels

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wpf-controls, hierarchical-data

[SQL_Table_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sveLM.png)

The image represent the data Im getting from SQL 2008 via web service to a WPF application to be represented in a Tree view with three levels(two drop down menus).For this purpose i would have to group this data with Bill_id (the first level in tree view), then product_id (the second level in tree view) and then option_id (the third level).
   At this time i currently don't have any idea if it is possible to group data like this with linq or whatever. or even if this is the right approach or not.
I'm not that good with hierarchical-data.
  Any kind of advice or sample code would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do with LINQ. You need to learn a bit of **SQL**, **LINQ** as well as **LINQtoSQL** to get a basic idea on how it works.

LINQtoSQL is one of the simplest ways to deal with data **Read/Write** from a database. IN LINQtoSQL you could drag and drop tables into the dbml file in visual studio itself and will be very easy to work with. You could access each table like a class file. The fields in the database table will be accessible like properties of a class.

See the LINQtoSQL query below. It is this simple and be used to read a list of data from database according to some condition.

```
var sqlquery = (from items in databaseContext.TableName
    where items.Bill_id >= 100 && items.Total_bill < 25000
    orderby items.Bill_id
    select items).ToList();
```

Like this you could do whatever you want with LINQ and SQL.
You could visit [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) as well as [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/) to get a basic idea of LINQ.